# XSLT - Delete XML nodes comparing dates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

For below XML i need to delete all XML nodes of only Unit 6000 when field StartDate is not equal to any of the StartDate items of unit 5000

I tried to match a template but does to seems to be a good match

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllRecords>
   <Records>
      <Record>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST1</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST2</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2020-05-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-02-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST3</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-02-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST4</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2010</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST5</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-06-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2020</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST5</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-093T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
      </Record>
   </Records>
</AllRecords>
```

xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    </xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="xs:date(//Items[Status = 'A' and ( Unit=6000)) ]/StartDate
    <xsl:template match="$date eq xs:date(//Items[Status = 'A' and Unit='5000']/StartDate)"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output XSLT code after deleting unit 6000 XML nodes as these 2 nodes dates does not match with any one the xml node of 5000

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllRecords>
   <Records>
      <Record>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST1</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST2</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2020-05-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-02-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST3</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2010</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST5</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
      </Record>
   </Records>
</AllRecords>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> delete all XML nodes of only Unit 6000 when field StartDate is not equal to any of the StartDate items of unit 5000

That should be very easy to accomplish using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)**:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Items[Unit=5000]" use="StartDate" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove items that do not have a matching item -->
<xsl:template match="Items[Unit=6000][not(key('k1', StartDate))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you I am laso trying to add enddate >= current date(), seems not working

Comment: Post a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: i have posted it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568820/xslt-filter-xml-nodes-with-dates-and-current-date

Answer (score 0):

Besides [@micheal.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66554213/11102282), this kind of problem can be easyly done with simple XPath/XSLT [patterns](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#patterns):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template 
       match="Items[Unit=6000][not(StartDate = ../Items[Unit=5000]/StartDate)]"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Check it [here](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVs4)

Comment: Thank you. I am also trying to check If EndDate not less than current time and its not working as expected