# XSLT - Filter XML nodes with dates and current date ()

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

For below XML i need to delete all XML nodes of only Unit 6000 when field StartDate is not equal to any of the StartDate items of unit 5000 and (also make sure startDate is less than equal to current date and EndDate is greater than or equal to current date)

I tried to match a template but does to seems to be a good match

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllRecords>
   <Records>
      <Record>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST1</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST2</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2020-05-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-02-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>1000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST3</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-02-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>5000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2020-12-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2000</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST4</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2020-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-03-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2010</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST5</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-01T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
         <Items>
            <EndDate>2021-06-31T00:00:00.000</EndDate>
            <PlantDetails>
               <PlantDetailsUS>
                  <company>2020</company>
                  <Newplant>TEST5</Newplant>
               </PlantDetailsUS>
            </PlantDetails>
            <StartDate>2021-01-093T00:00:00.000</StartDate>
            <Unit>6000</Unit>
            <Status>A</Status>
         </Items>
      </Record>
   </Records>
</AllRecords>
```

XSLT Code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template 
       match="Items[Unit=6000][not(StartDate = ../Items[Unit=5000]/StartDate)] [(StartDate &lt;= current-date())] [(EndDate &gt;= current-date())]"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *"I tried to match a template"* Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: it is already added to the question

Comment: And now it is visible.

Comment: Do note that `2021-01-093T00:00:00.000` is not a valid dateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing: in order to compare dates to current date you need XSLT 2.0 (or an alternative way to get the current date in XSLT 1.0, e.g. an extension function or a parameter).

Next, your input contains *dateTimes*, not *dates*. To make a valid comparison, you need to either compare them to the current dateTime or convert them to dates before comparing them to the current date. Try:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="Items[Unit=5000]" use="StartDate" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Items[Unit=6000][not(key('k1', StartDate)) or xs:date(substring(StartDate, 1, 10)) gt current-date() or xs:date(substring(EndDate, 1, 10)) lt current-date()]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: i am using 2.0 and endDate is not working with gt current date, it is still not deleting item             2020-12-31T00:00:00.000

Comment: It works when I try it: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4v7